# User session server log in GWT applications - any tools?

Tags: session, gwt, google-analytics, analytics

I need to track and log user interactions and requests within a GWT app. Can't use URL as in Google Analytics, so I guess it'd be some listener on the server side that would listen for user requests.

Is there any module that would allow me to collect, log and extract user behavior data from a GWT app?

Answer (score 0):

GWT (since 2.1) has remote logging capabilities. Have a look at [Developer's Guide - Logging](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideLogging#Remote_Logging) to see if this fits your needs.

Client logging is enabled by inheriting the GWT Logging module in your .gwt.xml file:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
```

Then you can log your user activities by using the logger:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("UserInteractions");
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "User clicked ok button");
```

If you now enable remote logging and use the RemoteLogHandler, the log message will be sent to the server by GWT-RPC and logged to the server logfile. Enable it by setting the following property:

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
```

But be aware that this can generate a lot of network traffic and server load if you log to much.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be nice if you paste some of the more important parts of your reference in your post. Just in case the link breaks down in the future.